# How to get all elements from index N to the end from an anonymous Perl array?

Tags: arrays, perl

In Perl 5, when we have a named array, e.g. `@a`, getting the elements from index `$N` onwards is simple with a bit of [slicing](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldata.html#Slices):

```
my @result = @a[$N..$#a];
```

Is there a standard way to do the same with an anonymous array, without having to supply the length explicitly? I.e. can this:

```
my @result = (0,1,2,3,4,5)[2..5];
```

or, more specifically, this:

```
my @result = (0,1,2,3,4,5)[$N..5];
```

be converted to something that does not need the upper range limit to be explicit? Perhaps some obscure Perl syntax? Maybe a bit of dicing instead of slicing?

PS: I have already written this as a function - I am looking for a more self-contained approach.

Comment: If you want to slice an anonymous array of `(0,1,2,3,4,5)` into `2 3 4 5`, then why not just write `(2,3,4,5)` in the first place?

Comment: @Blagovest Buyukliev: Because the starting index in my case is variable. I edited my question to reflect this requirement.

Comment: What is an "anonymous array"? :-)

Comment: @pst: I am merely continuing in the spirit of inconsistency that the Perl documentation cultivates by being unable to decide whether to call those things arrays or lists - which, incidentally, in many programming languages are completely different things :-)

Comment: Anonymous arrays and lists _are_ completely different things in Perl too. What thkala has here is a list, not an anonymous array.

Comment: I wonder why perl does not support `@a[$i..-1]` syntax, while it supports multiple slices using `,` inside `[...]` but not `-1` as the end index, why?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can `splice` it:

```
@result = splice @{[0..$M]}, $N;  # return $N .. $M
```

Answer (score 2):

I think mob's `splice` is the best option, but in the spirit of options:

```
my @result = reverse ((reverse 0..5)[0..$N+1]);
```

This returns the same result as the above example:

```
my @result = (0..5)[$N..5];
```

Comment: This returns `$N+1` items, but you want `$#{anonymous_array}-$N` items.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to give an array ref a name if you set it as the topic:

```
    sub returns_array_ref {[1 .. 5]}

    my @slice = map @$_[$n .. $#$_] => returns_array_ref;
```

Or if you are working with a list:

```
    sub returns_list {1 .. 5}

    my @slice = sub {@_[$n .. $#_]}->(returns_list);
```

Answer (score -1):

I just use the array variable to get the len:

```
@a = (1,2,3,4,5);
print @a[1..@a];
# output: (2,3,4,5)
```

Comment: That will not return `(2,3,4,5)`, but rather `(2,3,4,5,undef)`. If you run with warnings enabled and try to print this, you'll get a "Use of uninitialized value" warning.

The correct way is to use `$#a`.